# How to compare two columns in PIG and remove any same values regardless of upper/lower case

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 3 columns, an id column and 2 name columns.  Sometimes the 2 name columns are the same valued but one is upper case in one column and lower case in another. How do I remove these where the value is the same (or have similar characters) but the casing is different?

Ex:

a = load txt file
a = foreach a generate id, name1, name2

current output:

```
id1, james, JAMES
id2, tom, Tom
id3, Jim, Bob
id4, Bill, billy
```

expected output: only this 1 result below

a = compare name1 and name2 and if there are any similar characters in name1 that are also in name 2, filter these out

id3, Jim, Bob

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have loaded the data in Relation A and names are of type chararray.

```
A = FILTER A BY (LOWER(A.$1) != LOWER(A.$2))
DUMP A;
```

Comment: thank you this worked!  by the way, what does the $ indicate?

Comment: also @amit is there a way to filter out similar values?  for example, name1 = bill and name2 = billy and i want this record not part of my output. so something like the first 2 letters cannot be the same?

Comment: $ sign can be used to refer the fields by indexes, where index starts at 0. With regards to your second question you can refer to http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html and http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html